# Unable to remove "unreadable" virtual drives that constantly mount/unmount in Disk Management (Windows 10 - 1909)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, powershell, motherboard, mount

I build Windows 10 installations for mass deployment in the company I work for and I've come across a unique problem where these random ghost drives (nothing connected to the system) appear and disappear within Disk Management. The problem has a huge impact on system performance when running creative applications (video editing).

System specs:

- Model: HP Z440 Workstation
- Memory: 32 GiB DDR4
- Processor: Intel Xeon CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz
- Motherboard: Hewlett-Packard 212B
- Graphics: NVIDIA Quadro K2200 4.0 GB
- Operating System: Windows 10 (1909)

Workstation:

[image]

The version of Windows 10 being used is 1909. This version is in use because it's been qualified to run a specific set of creative software's that our clients use in house.

My process for building the images for mass deployment are:

1. Install Windows 10
2. At OOBE Screen enter audit mode
3. Install all base system devices with original manufacturer drivers by HP
4. Install Creative Software's
5. Run Sysprep
6. Capture image for mass deployment

The captured image works fine when deployed on the majority of our 200+ identical workstations, however there are a few that have presented this problem (see image below).

[image]

To clarify, these are not physical drives that are connected to the system in anyway whatsoever. Neither are they network drives either. I am aware of these three drives that for some reason remain mounted within Disk Management when installing Win10 1909 - they've always been there for us on every workstation and I've presumed it to be a mistake by Microsoft to have them sitting there after booting into a brand new Win10 desktop for the first time. After deploying the image and booting to the desktop for the first time we've always had to go to disk management and remove the drive letter from them so they do not appear as "Removable Disk" in the list of drives (so the user cannot see them). With these select few workstations we cannot remove the drive letter from them because they appear and disappear so fast you cannot interact with them.

So far I have tried the following:

- Reinstall Windows 10 (Clean) and re-install latest drivers. For this I have tried 1909 and 2004 - Same result.
- Update BIOS to latest version (same result)
- Physically unplugging the card reader
- Disconnected the card reader unit (there are 3 built-in card readers)
- Sat there in excruciating pain trying to quickly "catch" the drive in disk management and quickly remove it's drive letter before it disappears again. This worked for one machine only and it solved the problem - the machine performance went back to being optimal again. We still have other machines that this method hasn't worked on though.

Is anyone able to shed light on this, and perhaps offer advice on how I can get it fixed? PowerShell faster than the mouse method perhaps? My last resort is contacting HP to get the motherboard replaced but as they're out of warranty they're going to charge us to get all these machines fixed. If it helps, the drives usually always mount as E,F and G before they quickly unmount themselves again, but now they appear as "unreadable" (see screenshot)

[image]

The output of `gdr` within powershell is as follows:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> gdr

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                                                                                    CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                                                                                    ---------------
Alias                                  Alias
C                  75.58        156.67 FileSystem    C:\                                                                                                                                                                    Windows\system32
Cert                                   Certificate   \
Env                                    Environment
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Variable                               Variable
WSMan                                  WSMan
```

Comment: Do the disappearing drives appear in [overviews created in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1663565/1256347)?

Comment: Does mountvol /r (command prompt, admin) resolve it?

Comment: @Saaru Lindestøkke the most bizarre thing just happened. The command in that link `gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'` appears to have fixed the problem. The only drive listed when running it via PSsession was the C drive, but then after running it I went into Disk Management and the ghost drives are no longer there. I'm obviously super happy they're gone but perplexed as to how running that query has seemingly fixed it. Any ideas? And of course Thank YoU!!

Comment: Thanks for your input as well @Joep van Steen. Out of curiosity does `mountvol /r` pose any risk to the system (C:) drive?

Comment: @Mastaxx, no risk for c: drive.

Comment: Well, glad it helped. I have exactly 0 idea why that might have worked. I only Google and don't know what Im doing.

Comment: OK, well thanks for helping me get a system back to optimal condition despite the blind attack we both just executed on it. I still prefer to keep the question open so I can try out Joep's suggestion on another machine when I'm given access to it. Appreciate everyone's input so far, and to anyone else please feel free to comment if this issue has been encountered in the past or have light to shed on the matter. I want to understand the problem as much as I want to resolve it.

Comment: @Saaru Lindestøkke sadly the problem has re-appeared after a reboot of that system, and now the `gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'` command does not Allieviate the issue. it remains. Also, @Joep van Steen I can confirm that the `mountvol /r` command does not work on removing the drives either. Back to square one it seems. The drives are appearing "unreadable" - i've added the extra screenshot to my question post.

Comment: What is the output of the `gdr` command without any options? Are these other drives listed there? It might help you figure out what these "drives" are.

Comment: Just added that to the question as well. It appears as if the C Drive is the only mounted drive. I think these drives are not actually mounting so they're not appearing in the list when we do queries. I've even done `up` and `Enter` repeatedly very fast to try and "catch" some info as they appear and disappear but nothing shows up in the output when running `gdr`.

Comment: Are there other devices connected? Printers with slots for SD Cards for example? Are these machine laptops with card readers?

Comment: It's  Z440 Workstation and yes it does have a card reader unit that has three card readers. I just shut down the machine, disconnected the power and sata to the card reader unit and fired it up. Sadly the problem remains. That was worth a try though!

Comment: If the card reader is at fault I wonder if re-imaging the machine with the card reader disconnected would make any difference? I could give that a go tomorrow.

Comment: Also.. device Manager > View > Show hidden devices > I get extra item "Storage Volumes". Perhaps worth comparing machine with and without the phantom drive phenomena.

Comment: Just checked this too. On the problem computer there are a few instances of "Volume" that are greyed out. In their properties section it says `"Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer. (Code 45)"`. Would you suggest uninstalling the device? Also, I compared it to a system that doesn't have the phantom drive problem and there happens to be even more instances of greyed out "Volume" on that one.

Comment: I can not make recommendation, I just happened to notice it while looking for hints..

Comment: I'm not sure about these hidden devices or how to handle them. Happy to try anything at this point if clear instructions are given on that front.

Comment: I can confirm that i have just finished re-imaging the machine with the card reader completely disconnected from the motherboard. Sadly the issue still remains.

Comment: You could write a powershell script which queries all disks every second. Than print out the hardware ID for each disk. The hardware ID will tell you how the disk is connected (USB, IDE, SATA, ...). You can also print out other information (like driver name) but you will definitely know what kind of device it is.